# Can I use a variable inside cursor declaration?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

Is this code valid?

```
-- Zadavatel Login ID
DECLARE @ZadavatelLoginId nvarchar(max) =
            (SELECT TOP 1 LoginId 
             FROM
                 (SELECT Z.LoginId, z.Prijmeni, k.spojeni 
                  FROM TabCisZam Z 
                  LEFT JOIN TabKontakty K ON Z.ID = K.IDCisZam 
                  WHERE druh IN (6,10)) t1
             LEFT JOIN
                 (SELECT ko.Prijmeni, k.spojeni, ko.Cislo 
                  FROM TabCisKOs KO 
                  LEFT JOIN TabKontakty K ON K.IDCisKOs = KO.id 
                  WHERE druh IN (6, 10)) t2 ON t1.spojeni = t2.spojeni 
                                            AND t1.Prijmeni = t2.Prijmeni
             WHERE 
                 t2.Cislo = (SELECT CisloKontOsoba 
                             FROM TabKontaktJednani 
                             WHERE id = @IdKJ))
        
-- Pokud je řešitelský tým prázdný
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TabKJUcastZam WHERE IDKJ = @IdKJ)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ac_loginy CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
        -- Zadavatel
        SELECT @ZadavatelLoginId
END
ELSE BEGIN
```

I am trying to pass the variable `@ZadavatelLoginId` into the cursor declaration and SSMS keeps telling me there is a problem with the code even though it is working.

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure et_TabKontaktJednani_ANAFRA_Tis_Notifikace, Line 575 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Larnu perhaps OP is moving from plsql to tsql and doesn't know you don't need cursors

Comment: check the picture, please

Comment: @ondrejheryan the picture is of text and is not helpful.

Comment: @Larnu the error is:
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure et_TabKontaktJednani_ANAFRA_Tis_Notifikace, Line 575 [Batch Start Line 7]
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Why do you want to use a cursor here? It is a scalar value so there is nothing to iterate.

Comment: @SeanLange The variable will be followed by UNION and another SELECT statement

Comment: There are several things here that are a bit strange to me. You have a left join but then your where clause forces to behave like an inner join. You have a subquery in your where clause which will cause errors if the subquery returns more than 1 row. That subquery in the where clause should be an inner join instead. Then there is the whole part about this just building stuff that you are going to use in a cursor. The cursor itself is a major red flag that the process is going the wrong direction as they are rarely a good choice because the performance is horrible.

Comment: You would be better off explaining the problem you are trying to solve, rather than giving us your attempt which isn't working that is very likely to be using the wrong methodology.

Comment: Ok, the variable stores the login name of a user (chosen inside ERP) - it will always have a scalar value. If the condition is not met, the cursor will be declared with the variable @ZadavatelLoginId followed by UNION and other SELECT(S) as I mentioned earlier. Now I can see that the problem is probably rather in the variable declaration than in the cursor.
The variable stores a user name out of table TabCisZam (employees) which is joined to table TabCisKOs (business partners, employees etc - application input) 'over' the table TabKontakty (Contacts). 
This is probably for another question.

Comment: I suggest your best path forward is explaining what you want to use the cursor to accomplish, and ask how you could do it without a cursor at all.

Comment: It iterates over ERP users (logins) and sends each of them a notification with a stored procedure that has an addressee parameter that only accepts a single loginId - (sort of like sending emails

Comment: You seem to have conflicting statements: "the variable stores the login name of a user (chosen inside ERP) - it will always have a scalar value" and "It iterates over ERP users (logins)". If the variable will only contains one login ID, how do you expect to iterate over multiple users?  As written, your cursor definition selects a single scalar, so it will always yield exactly one row.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything in your posted query that could trigger the specific message that you listed. You might get an error if the subquery `(SELECT CisloKontOsoba FROM TabKontaktJednani WHERE id = @IdKJ)` returned more than one value, but that error would be a very specific "Subquery returned more than 1 value...".

However, as written, your cursor query is a single select of a scalar, which would never yield anything other than a single row.

If you need to iterate over multiple user IDs, but wish to separate your selection query from your cursor definition, what you likely need is a table variable than can hold multiple user IDs instead of a scalar variable.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @ZadavatelLoginIds TABLE (LoginId nvarchar(max))
INSERT @ZadavatelLoginIds
SELECT t1.LoginId
FROM ...

DECLARE ac_loginy CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
    SELECT LoginId
    FROM @ZadavatelLoginIds
OPEN ac_loginy
DECLARE @LoginId nvarchar(max)

FETCH NEXT FROM ac_loginy INTO @LoginId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    ... Send email to @LoginId ...

    FETCH NEXT FROM ac_loginy INTO @LoginId
END

CLOSE ac_loginy
DEALLOCATE ac_loginy
```

A #Temp table can also be used in place of the table variable with the same results, but the table variable is often more convenient to use.

As others have mentioned, I believe that your login selection query is overly complex. Although this was not the focus of your question, I still suggest that you attempt to simplify it.

An alternative might be something like:

```
SELECT Z.LoginId 
FROM TabKontaktJednani KJ
JOIN TabCisKOs KO ON KO.Cislo = KJ.CisloKontOsoba
JOIN TabCisZam Z ON Z.Prijmeni = KO.Prijmeni
JOIN TabKontakty K ON K.IDCisZam = Z.ID
WHERE KJ.id = @IdKJ
AND K.druh IN (6,10)
```

The above is my attempt to rewrite your posted query after tracing the relationships. I did not see any `LEFT JOINS` that were not superseded by other conditions that forced them into effectively being inner joins, so the above uses inner joins for everything. I have assumed that the `druh` column is in the `TabKontakty` table. Otherwise I see no need for that table. *I do not guarantee that my re-interpretation is correct though.*

Answer (score -1):

How about you create a #temp table for each sub query since the problem is coming up due to the sub queries?

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
(
    LoginID nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2
(
    ko.Prijmeni nvarchar(max), 
    k.spojeni nvarchar(max), 
    ko.Cislo nvarchar(max)
)
```

Comment: This is bad advice. You should generally be looking for ways to use fewer temp tables, not more.